# AWS Kinesis Firehose delivery stream doesn't use SSL when sending data to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a Kinesis Firehose delivery stream that is sending data to S3. All works fine until I set my S3 bucket with `enforceSSL: true` , at which point all data stop reaching the S3 bucket. How can I make the delivery stream use SSL? or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How do you `enforceSSL: true`? Do normal write operations by you yourself still work?

Comment: I'm using `CDK`, it's one of the bucket properties in CDK

Comment: CDK wraps a buket policy to enforce

Comment: @erik258 thanks, yes. it adds this to the policy: `Deny  │ s3:*   │ AWS:* │ "Bool": {                                   "aws:SecureTransport": "false"  }`

Answer (score 0):

firehose use TLS to send data to S3 by default, you can check that in your cloud trail event where you can find :
"tlsDetails": {
**"tlsVersion": "TLSv1.2",**
"cipherSuite": "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256"
}
i think you have something wrong with your policy document, can you share your policy?

you can use this to force SSL

{
"Id": "ExamplePolicy",
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Sid": "AllowSSLRequestsOnly",
"Action": "s3:*",
"Effect": "Deny",
"Resource": [
"arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET",
"arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*"
],
"Condition": {
"Bool": {
"aws:SecureTransport": "false"
}
},
"Principal": "*"
}
]
}

Comment: It is easier to read if you use formatting. See: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help